# HTTP1.1 Behaviour different in XP and Win7?

Tags: http, internet-explorer

In our intranet, we have a directory that uses AJAX to search for and display contact information.

In Windows XP with IE8 and HTTP1.1 enabled, it all works fine.
In Windows 7 with IE8 and HTTP1.1 enabled, I get a blank page when searching.
In Windows 7 with IE and HTTP1.1 disabled, it all works fine.

Is there a difference in HTTP1.1 behaviour between XP and 7 that could explain this?
Is there something I should check server side in Apache?

Answer (score 2):

HTTP 1.1 is a protocol that has nothing to do with the Operating System. It's used by browsers. Its main advantage over HTTP 1.0 is that it will use the same TCP connection for several HTTP requests by default (this is called Persistence in 1.1), whereas with HTTP 1.0 by default you establish one TCP connection for each HTTP Transaction - which is a waste of network performance and usage.

So your question is really: Is the HTTP 1.1 implementation different in IE8 depending on the OS? It's entirely possible. You could check the Apache access.log, but it's a pain in a neck to look into that. You're better off installing [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and capturing your HTTP requests from each of the computers. To compare the requests, simply identify the correct TCP connection, right click, and do a "Follow TCP Stream". It will then show you a re-assembled text version of all the packets and you will see the HTTP Headers and Body from both the client and server side.